# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I'm trying to write Unity plugin to give access to `getSimOperatorName()` and `getNetworkOperatorName()` functions of Native Android. In Android Studio I am creating an AAR lib with 2 classes, that you can see below...

```
package com.eppz.myplugin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class My_Plugin extends Activity
{
    static Context context = MyApplication.getContext();
    static String test = "";

    public static String getMessage()
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        try {
            test = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
        }catch (Exception e){
            test = e.getMessage();
        }
        return test;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
package com.eppz.myplugin;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
```

Error Log:

```
05-08 05:23:26.245 30107-30152/? I/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
      at com.eppz.myplugin.My_Plugin.getMessage(My_Plugin.java:15)
      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticStringMethod (IntPtr clazz, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEngine.Androi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did you add your application class name in the AndroidManifest.xml file? `<application android:name=".MyApplication">`

Comment: I noticed that you asked a fellow up question. Is this problem solved? If yes, just  accept the solution that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `My_Plugin` activity is initialized and `static Context context = MyApplication.getContext();` is executed, your `MyApplication` instance has not been created yet, i.e. `onCreate()` has not been called, thus `context` is `null` when you request it with `MyApplication.getContext()`.

You should be able to fix this by calling `MyApplication.getContext()` late on, for example in the `getMessage()` method itself:

```
public static String getMessage()
{
    context = MyApplication.getContext();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the application context from within your activity by using the method "getApplicationContext()". In this case you don't need it, so from your activity you can call the getSystemService() method directly.

```
     public class My_Plugin extends Activity
        {
            static String test = "";

            public static String getMessage()
            {
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

                try {
                    test = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    test = e.getMessage();
                }
                return test;
            }
        }
```